# UNITY How do I change image position?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ecs

Below is a snippet of code thats running every update but when I log the local position of the image it still says 0,0,0 when it should be 10,10,10. What am I doing wrong??? Ultimately I am trying to understand how to programmatically move an image around on screen

```
public partial class MainCanvasSystem : SystemBase
{
    protected override void OnUpdate()
    {
        if (MainGameObjectCanvas.Instance != null && SystemAPI.HasSingleton<MainEntityCanvas>())
        {
            Entity mainEntityCanvasEntity = SystemAPI.GetSingletonEntity<MainEntityCanvas>();
            LocalToWorld targetLocalToWorld = SystemAPI.GetComponent<LocalToWorld>(mainEntityCanvasEntity);
            Canvas canvas = MainGameObjectCanvas.Instance;
            Image image = canvas.GetComponentInChildren<Image>();

            var rect = image.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            rect.localScale.Set(10,10,10);
            Debug.Log(rect.localPosition.x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: rect.anchoredPosition.Set( 10000,100000); doesnt work either

Comment: and if I do image.enabled = false; then the image goes away so I know Im enteracting with the right component

Comment: Setting anchoredPosition is generally the right way to do it. Is it's position being controlled by another element like a horizontal layout group or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is general misunderstanding here.

```
rect.localScale.Set(10,10,10);
```

does .. nothing!

[`Transform.localScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localScale.html) is a [**property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) and returns a **COPY** of a [`Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) [**struct**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct).

You are calling [`Vector3.Set`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Set.html) on it which replaces the values within that [`Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) **copy**, yes, but then you never actually apply it anywhere.

=> you need to actually **set** the property!

You rather *would* do e.g.

```
rect.locaScale = Vector3.one * 10;
```

or

```
rect.localScale = new Vector3(10,10,10);
```

However, this said, changing a `localScale` won't change the **position** at all. The [`RectTransform.anchoredPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-anchoredPosition.html) is probably rather the one to go with.

Comment: my man!!! ty so much! I'm a java dev so I assumed I was calling a setter. I still have no clue what that Set function does guess i gotta look into that. but ya rect.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(1,100); worked like you said

Comment: So if the Set function returns void how would I use the set function correctly? How would I actually apply those changes?

Comment: @JakeGergen usually you don't at all ^^ there are cases where it might be less allocation and GC intense reusing the same `Vector3` (field or local variable) and replace its components all at once in loops etc .. but I barely used it whatsoever so far. It is basically just a shorthand for `someVector.x = ...; someVevtor.y = ...; someVector.z = ...;` which again yes it changes the values stored in this vector .. but it is just a struct and not connected to anything. You need to set something to Unities properties so that those call certain c++ native engine setters under the hood